# How can i change my script to list files on the subfolders too?

Tags: list, file, perl

I want to change my script to list the files on the subfolders. lets say i choose the folder /lib64 y would like to do the search on the subfolders too
Thanks for your help.

I need help only to list not only the folder given but also the subfolfers

Below my script, working without any problems....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

system("clear");
my $dev;
my $ino;
my $mode;
my $nlink;
my $uid;
my $gid;
my $rdev;
my $size;
my $atime;
my $mtime;
my $ctime;
my $blksize;
my $blocks;
my $perm;
my $tmp1;
my $tmp2;
clear;

print " \n";
print "Please enter the Directory you want to list : ";
my $dir = <STDIN>;
chomp $dir;
print "Directory selected is ------------> $dir | \n \n";

print "Please enter the minimum size (in bytes) of files you want to list 
: ";
my $sz = <STDIN>;
chomp $sz;
print "Minimal size of files (in bytes)-----------------> $sz | \n \n";
print "...........Please wait, preparing the file listing....... \n \n";

sleep 6;

opendir (DIR, $dir ) or die "Cannot open $dir";

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
     $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat("$dir/$file");


$perm = sprintf("%04o", $mode & 07777);
$tmp1 = int(($size/$sz));
$tmp2 = length($file);


if (($tmp1 > $tmp2) && ($perm =~ /.[^5410]../)) {

    print "List of files in --> $dir | ";
    print("File Name: -$file- | Size in bytes -$size- \n");
}
}

closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: Consider [File::Find](https://perldoc.pl/File::Find), or the nicer CPAN module [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule).

Comment: But then those "files" themselves may be subfolders as well, right?  So you need code to work recursively -- to also go through all subfolders it finds.  This is not as simple while there are very good libraries.  Installed with the system, you'll find [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) .  Another popular one is [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule), and there are yet others. There are articles around on how to use them effectively, as well.

Comment: Can someone show me how to use one of those modules? or guide me to a good article that talks about it?

Comment: Questions like this come up often. I encourage you to search Stackoverflow -- it's a skill that will repay every single time you have coding related needs.  For example, search the perl tag for `File::Find` and [get this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bperl%5d%20File%3a%3aFind), where the first few I clicked on (judged by title) had complete example programs.  Then there's [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+File%3A%3AFind%3A%3ARule) on `File::Find::Rule`.   Then, a perlmonks [guide](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=217166) came up.

Comment: Then you got an answer to your specific questions using `Path::Iterator::Rule`. Also, for that module [this tutorial](https://perlmaven.com/finding-files-in-a-directory-using-perl) came up as well.  That's hopefully plenty of resources.  And of course let us know if things still aren't in good shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of iterating recursively using [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule). Also, [File::stat](https://perldoc.pl/File::stat) is a much simpler interface to stat fields.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Iterator::Rule;
use File::Basename;
use File::stat;

print "Please enter the Directory you want to list : ";
chomp(my $dir = readline *STDIN);
print "Please enter the minimum size (in bytes) of files you want to list : ";
chomp(my $sz = readline *STDIN);

my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new->not_dir->size(">=$sz");
my $next = $rule->iter($dir);
while (defined(my $file = $next->())) {
  my $stat = stat $file or die "Failed to stat $file: $!";
  my $mode = $stat->mode;
  my $size = $stat->size;
  my $basename = basename $file;
  ...
}
```

Comment: @AlbertMarceloMariani Then kindly consider accepting the answer ? (By cllicking on the check mark.)  And see the link in the comment under your question.

Comment: No problem. Thank you